# Missing Files and Folders in Google Drive API

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm having issues with using Google Drive's API and I am wondering if I am using the API with credentials properly. I'm using a credentials.json file to upload into My Drive and not a Shared Drive.

```
    string jsonContent;
    string folderName = "CSV";

    AssetManager assetM = context.Assets;
    string fileName = "credentials.json";
    using (Stream stream = assetM.Open(fileName))
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        jsonContent = reader.ReadToEnd();

    }

    var credential = GoogleCredential.FromJson(jsonContent).CreateScoped(DriveService.ScopeConstants.Drive);

    var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = credential
    });
```

This is how I'm establishing my DriveService. I know that it is better to go with Application Default Credentials and I'll look into that deeper after this. But my issue is that I'm trying to Create Files/Folders within My Drive and they're not appearing on My Drive. They exist when I use `service.Files.List()`. But they don't actually appear on My Drive.

```
string uploadedFileId;

using (Stream assetStream = assetM.Open("SampleCSV.csv"))
{
  
    var fileMetaData = new Google.Apis.Drive.v3.Data.File()
    {
        Name = "SampleCSV.csv",
        MimeType = "application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet",
        Parents = new List<string>() { DirectoryId.ToString() }
    };

    string mimeType = "text/csv";

    FilesResource.CreateMediaUpload request = service.Files.Create(fileMetaData, assetStream, mimeType);
    request.Fields = "*";
    
    var results = await request.UploadAsync(CancellationToken.None);
    if (results.Status == Google.Apis.Upload.UploadStatus.Failed)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine($"Error uploading file: {results.Exception.Message}");

    }
    uploadedFileId = request.ResponseBody?.Id;
```

So in this section here, I perform the upload and it uploads successfully into the folder with the `Directory.Id` that I specified. But without that specified in Parent, then it succeeds on upload but it doesn't upload into the root drive (My Drive). So where exactly is it being uploaded into? Is it being uploaded into the drive of the service account? That's my best guess but I'm not sure how to proceed from here. There are probably other bits of information that I'm not understanding well and anything knowledge would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: @Babanana Yes it does. I was more or less familiar with the idea that there exists a drive associated with using a service account, but I'm not familiar with them though. Suppose the goal of the folder/file creation is to be used by different people and google accounts, what would be the best way to accomplish this? It seems like using Drive Picker API may be the best option. I was just having issues trying to implement it before.

Comment: you can implement your solution using this instead. https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2

Comment: A service account is a dummy user files are stored on its drive account unless you supply a folder to upload and grant it access to a folder on your own account.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo I'm reading your article on https://www.daimto.com/google-drive-authentication-c/ . I was wondering if they way you did the credentials here would suit my mobile apps needs. My other concern when reading it was that the client id and secrets would be coded in and I'm not sure if that's supposed to be available.

Comment: I thought a service account would be preferred as it is an app that ideally many users would be able to access their drives to manage data but service accounts appear to require shared access in order to do that which is unideal. I explored Google Picker but there isn't much resources for it for mobile development using C# so I decided against it.

Comment: Service accounts should ideally be used when the Developer has access to the account.    If its user data you should use oauth2

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo So in this case where you needed a client secrets for oauth2 in your article here, https://www.daimto.com/google-oauth2-csharp/ . I saw you mention in  another post and commented that for android apps, it doesn't require client secrets and only client ids. So could I still use that snippet omitting the client secret section?

Comment: If its an android app then you need to create mobile app project on google developer console.   I have never gotten that to work with C# as its not supported.  Your going to have to go with android or ios app i think.   I havent even seen it working with flutter.

Comment: @LindaLawton-DaImTo Would you mind explaining a little further about what's not supported? Like using OAuth2 and C#? And that I would have to go with Android and Java shown in this https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start ?

Comment: If you get any form of Mobile Oauth2 working in C# I would love to see the code.  I have  tried I can never get it to work.